# What does the '+' do in the "date" command?

Tags: date

The following gives me a date:

```
$ date +%Y%m%d                                                                             
20201012
```

This doesn't:

```
$ date %Y%m%d
date: invalid date ‘%Y%m%d’
```

The man page says to have `+` in front of `FORMAT`. What is the importance of `+` other than being the correct syntax?

```
date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `info date`:

```
 If given an argument that starts with a ‘+’, ‘date’ prints the
current date and time (or the date and time specified by the ‘--date’
option, see below) in the format defined by that argument, which is
similar to that of the ‘strftime’ function.  Except for conversion
specifiers, which start with ‘%’, characters in the format string are
printed unchanged.  The conversion specifiers are described below.
```

You can for example do this:

```
date +"The year is %Y"
The year is 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` introduces a date format string.